# Android: AR View not smooth even using High pass filter or low pass filter

Tags: android, augmented-reality, camera-calibration, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

Creating an application in which show different planes on air while using Camera (Augmented reality view). even using the filters the view has no smoothness even I search different post and already try google code. also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119672/android-low-pass-filter-and-high-pass-filter) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) post as well.

here is my code:

```
int rangeDelta = range - MINIMUM_RANGE;
        float zoomDelta = (MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL - MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL) * (float) (rangeDelta / (float) (MAX_RANGE - MINIMUM_RANGE));
        zoomLevel = MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL - zoomDelta;
        if (map != null) {
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPos, zoomLevel));
        }
```

and here is my Smooth function:

```
private float smooth(float oldValue, float newValue) {
        float delta = newValue - oldValue;
        return oldValue + (INERTIA * delta);
    }
```

INERTIA value is 0.035 hard coded

Even then object are shivering.

sorry for bad english.